# Can I see what critical section the odbc dll is waiting on using windbg?

Tags: deadlock, windbg

I took a dump of a hung process and I've got three threads waiting on this one:

```
ntdll.dll ZwWaitForKeyedEvent
ntdll.dll RtlSleepConditionVariableCS
kernel32.dll SleepConditionVariableCS
odbc32.dll EnterCancelCSAndDbcCS
odbc32.dll FreeStmt
odbc32.dll SQLFreeStmt
oqpers.dll ZED_SQLFreeStmt
```

Is there any way to see the critical section in `odbc32.dll`?  I'd like to know what thread it is waiting on.

Comment: What's the output of `!locks -v`?

Comment: There might be too many to look at.  I think it has been scrolling output for almost an hour now.  I guess I'd have to output the results to a file or something.  I just cancelled it using ctrl+break.

Comment: Try !cs -l , Display only the locked critical sections. NB your callstack don't imply that there is a critical section involved

Answer (score 0):

From the `kv` output, you should be able to see the critical section address passed into [SleepConditionVariableCS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms686301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Then use the `!critsec [address]` command to see if anybody currently owns it.

But according to the above stack trace, the thread is still waiting on the condition, and hasn't tried to re-acquire the lock yet. Trying to find why someone hasn't signaled the conditional event isn't going to be an easy thing.

I would poke around the parameters and stack of odbc32!EnterCancelCSAndDbcCS. From the name it looks like it may be using two critical sections, one of which may be locked preventing the other threads from signaling the condition.